# How to determine beamforming pattern?

Tags: antenna, matlab, beamforming

I have a beamforming vector, which includes amplitude and phase information. How can I determine the corresponding beamforming pattern for the antenna and plot it in Matlab? For example, I have a beamforming vector (0.05-0.02i，0.1+0.04i).

Comment: Is that vector the phase and amplitude response for a 2-element array?  If so, that vector is only valid for a single beam pointing direction.

Comment: Thank you for the response, actually my transmitter beamforming vector is 1x10 size, here I just take a simple example with 2-element. But I just want to know how to plot the transmitting beamforming pattern in matlab with this beamforming vector.